# How can I replace Elastic logo from my Dashboard (top left ) and login screen?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack, elk

I have made a dashboard using ELK stack taking the real-time data from trackers and pushing it in postgresql through logstash. I have deployed it on my server. But the organization requirement is that to replace the logo with their own logo for presentation (demonstration) in front of stakeholders. I have searched a lot but no trust worthy answer I have found. I am using following versions of ELK stack:

```
> Elastic 7.12.1 Logstash 7.12.1 Kibana 7.12.1
```

I am using Windows 10 operating system. Looking for solution. Thank you

Comment: Changing the logo is not supported, there are some un-official ways to do it, but you will need to rebuild kibana, it is a lot of work and I'm not sure if the current license allows it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is a dashboard that you want to present, then you can embed functionalities of Kibana: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/embedding.html

This way, you can create your own webpage with your custom logo, and embed the dashboard in an . Please check the docs for an exhaustive how-to

Comment: Thank you for your solution, but When I embed the code in simple HTML page, it ask for authentication and when I provide the credentials it again redirect to the same login page without my actual dashboard. I have provide the "?auth_provider_hint=anonymous1"  in the URL of iframe but still the issue persist. Please need further guideline.

Comment: this is the url which i have embedded <iframe src="http://myIP:5601/app/dashboards?auth_provider_hint=anonymous1#/view/d2f8cf90-afcd-11eb-8d63-6d889e46fc6e?embed=true........